# Android prevent brightness from dropping below some percentage

Tags: screen-brightness

I had the following situation. In my phone I might accidentally drop the brightness to 0.  .When that happened I could not do anything. I had a hard time unlocking my lock-screen using a pin code. I had to use some flashlight to be able to unlock my phone and reset the brightness. Now in order to prevent this in the future I want to set a threshold (lets say 30%) that the brightness will not drop below that threshold. Is that even possible?

Comment: The minimum brightness mode is as far as I know a fixed value that can't be changed on an unrooted device. A too dark brightness is very rare, usually it is the other way around. I would recommend to prepare your device: enable developer options and ADB plus authenticate a PC by connecting it. For entering the pin use a simple USB keyboard that works blind and after unlocking you should be able to set the screen brightness via ADB.

Comment: [Apps like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mlhg.screenfilter) allow you to set brightness level

Comment: You can use ADB to setup the brightness:
`adb shell settings put screen_brightness 255`
the value can be between 0 and 255.